# Return JSON inside data[] php

Tags: php, json

I'm using the following to pull some data fro facebook:

```
$tagData = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/123456789/friends?access_token='.$access_token);

echo $tagData;
```

This produces e.g.:

```
{"data":
[
{"name":"Jonathan Montiel","id":"28125695"},
{"name":"Jackson C. Gomes","id":"51300292"}
],
"paging":{"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/123456789\/friends?access_token=5148835fe&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100060104"}}
```

**QUESTION** How I can just return ONLY what's inside the `[...]` including the `[ ]`?

Desired result:

```
[
{"name":"Jonathan James","id":"28125695"},
{"name":"Jackson C. Cliveden","id":"51300292"}
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$tagData = json_decode( $tagData, true );

$data = $tagData['data'];

echo json_encode( $data );
```

This basically converts the JSON to an array, extracts the desired part and returns this again as JSON-encoded.

**EDIT**

**[Example Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wda-v0b)**

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Works fine for me. I just had a type in the first line: your variable is spelled with a captial `D`, I had a lowercase `d`.

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` and reencode with `json_encode` necessary part of the response. Following is going to work for you:

```
$tagData = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/123456789/friends?access_token='.$access_token);

$tagData = json_decode($tagData);
echo json_encode($tagData->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sirco for the inspiration, this works although how its different to answer given I have no clue!

```
$tagData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/123456789/friends?access_token='.$access_token), true );

$data = $tagData['data'];

echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: See my comment how this is different ,-)